# How can I build HornetQ from source?

Tags: maven, hornetq

I'm not new to maven. but I don't know why my maven use 1.1.1 version of maven-plugin, hornet-maven-plugin. the reason I say about the version is that the repository doesn't have the version. So I think I have to change the version of plugin that the repository has.

the soure code is here( https://github.com/verystrongjoe/hornetq/tree/master/examples/jms/clustered-queue ).

I downloaded that to my local disk. and I imported to my eclipse. 
but the result was an error like below.

```
Failure to find org.hornetq:hornetq-maven-plugin:pom:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT in http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local 
 repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-public-repository-group has elapsed or updates are forced
```

If you go to the repository http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public , there are 1.1.0 or 1.0.0.

please let me explain about this.. thanks in adavance.

Comment: What's the dependency in the POM?

Answer (score 2):

You can see the answer on [Line 716](https://github.com/verystrongjoe/hornetq/blob/master/pom.xml#L716) of the super-POM:

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hornetq-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     </plugin>
```

It sounds like you might not be knowledgeable enough to work on the edge of the github source. Perhaps you should work with one of the recent [release tags](https://github.com/verystrongjoe/hornetq/tree/HornetQ_2_2_23_AS7_Final) instead?

Comment: thanks, I solved this issue changing the version of the plugin to 1.1.0. If the version is 2.3.0.CR2, the most recent version, it's worked without error.

Answer (score 2):

You are forking and trying to work with an *in-development* SNAPSHOT version of HornetQ. That normally requires more work than using released versions. Tip one: consider working only with released versions of HQ.

If not, be aware that:

- HornetQ does not release `*-SNAPSHOT` versions of artifacts to Maven repositories. That is the reason you won't find them at that JBoss Maven repository. BTW, See here for comments with regards to figuring out dependencies of HornetQ examples https://github.com/hornetq/hornetq#recreating-the-examples
- See here about the minimal instructions of using the SNAPSHOT version of the `hornetq-maven-plugin` https://github.com/hornetq/maven-hornetq-plugin/blob/master/README.md

Please notice that the content of each of those links is small. I could have copied their content here but I didn't. My point is: these projects have README files which address your issues, **you should always check the README**.